# How to get Cookies from ServletContextListener?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i am new in Servlet and JSP and i want to grab all the cookies once my web app is running so i am using `ServletContextListener` to deploy what inside it once my web app is run !, so how can i get all cookies within it ?
i am trying to do the following :

```
public class listener implements ServletContextListener {

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
 HttpServletRequest request ;
 Cookie s[]=request.getCookies();
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {

}}
```

Comment: You have to have a real request from which to extract the cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't need all the cookies [ie cookies of all users], but you need cookies of particular request. You can get them inside `HttpServlet`'s doGet() or doPost() methods, depending on the request type:

```
 public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        //...
    }
 }
```

Comment: The things i want my code execute once the web app is on , not some Servlet or JSP or Specific Page

Comment: The problem is that cookies come from HttpRequest and HttpRequest is the only point where you can get them. If for any reason you want to keep all the incoming cookies you may create a Filter and intercept all the cookies there. What task are you trying to solve with getting all the cookies?